# Should I use Upsert IAction method or Edit and Create separately?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, edit, upsert

I'm new and learning how to build an MVC application and while implementing CRUD operations and I'm wondering if the logic from Edit and Create should be placed inside one single method as some tutorials seem to suggest.

Is this a good practice, and why?

Does this respect SOLID principles?

Thank you so much in advance <3

Comment: If you are creating API then you can read about rest API standards to understand how the API should look like. For quick answer you should have different actions for create and update operations. Post for create and put for update.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the same request model for both create and update methods; however, they should still be separate endpoints for a few key reasons:

- Security: You may want to implement additional controller logic around the editing of existing entities.
- Different input required: To update an existing entity, you need to know the ID of the entity to be updated.  Generally, this is passed in the form of a URL parameter in a PUT request.  For example, to update user 2, you would send a PUT request to /api/users/2 with a request body containing the JSON of your create/edit user request model.
- Clearer logging: By utilizing separate request types, it is much easier to interpret basic access logs.  For example, if you see several 500 response codes in access logs for PUT requests, you are able to focus your investigation on the update logic.

With that said, there isn't really one right way.  However, most development teams (including one-person teams) will opt for separate methods for some of the reasons above.